# Android System Overlay 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-softkeyboard

```
    // fetch window manager object 
     mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
     // set layout parameter of window manager
     WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                30, // width of layout 30 px
                200, // height is equal to full screen
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, // Type Ohone, These are non-application windows providing user interaction with the phone (in particular incoming calls).
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
               // WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH // this window won't ever get key input focus  
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
                );      
     mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;   
     //mParams.setTitle("Load Average");

     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     mWindowManager.addView(touchLayout, mParams);

     touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

This is just a snippet of the code.  My first issue was receiving touches in the view which this will do, however, the soft keyboard fails to open when touching edit text boxes in other applications while this service is running.  I have tried various flags which fix the issue, but I loose the ability to register the touch event to the portion of the screen as displayed above in the code.

I'm out of ideas, does anyone have any idea of where I am going wrong, or an alternative solution for Android 4.2.2+?

Comment: I assume you're using the standard Android keyboard, and not a 3rd party one, right?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    dialog.setContentView(new EditText(this));
    dialog.show();
```